# HAProxy doesn't recognize SSL

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl, haproxy

I have some problems with HAProxy and OpenSSL..

Since I'm trying to create a cloud server with a load-balancer that deals with HTTPS, I want to use specific versions of HAProxy and OpenSSL..

My problem is that when I compile OpenSSL and HAProxy with Openssl, then HAProxy doesn't recognize the SSL functions.. You will find the different commands I have used below.

**Compile OpenSSL 1.0.2d**

```
sudo apt-get -y install libssl-dev libpcre3 make
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2d.tar.gz
tar xzvf openssl-1.0.2d.tar.gz
rm openssl-1.0.2d.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2d
./config --prefic=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl --libdir=lib shared
make && make install
```

**Compile HAProxy**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libpcre3-dev
wget www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/src/haproxy-1.5.14.tar.gz
tar xzvf haproxy-1.5.14.tar.gz
rm haproxy-1.5.14.tar.gz
cd haproxy-1.5.14
make TARGET=linux26 CPU=generic USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_PCRE=1
make install
(apt-get install haproxy) <--- To get HAProxy as a service
```

Then, when I use the command `haproxy -vv`, I get:

```
HA-Proxy version 1.5.14 2015/07/02
Copyright 2000-2015 Willy Tarreau <willy@haproxy.org>

Build options :
  TARGET  = linux26
  CPU     = generic
  CC      = gcc
  CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing
  OPTIONS = USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_PCRE=1

Default settings :
  maxconn = 2000, bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 8192, maxpollevents = 200

Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
Built without zlib support (USE_ZLIB not set)
Compression algorithms supported : identity
Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
OpenSSL library supports prefer-server-ciphers : yes
Built with PCRE version : 8.31 2012-07-06
PCRE library supports JIT : no (USE_PCRE_JIT not set)
Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND

Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result OK
Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.
```

Here, we see that HAProxy is running with OpenSSL, but when I use my `haproxy.cfg` file:

```
global
    log localhost local0 notice
    maxconn 2048
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    timeout connect     5000ms
    timeout client      50000ms
    timeout server      50000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    maxconn 2048
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

frontend https-in
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/certif.pem
    maxconn 2048
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    default_backend internalProxy

# Internal Proxys
backend internalProxy
    balance roundrobin
    # internal proxys

# Test
backend testExternalProxy
    errorfile 503 /root/haproxy/code202.http

# Statistics
listen stats *:8010
    mode http
    log global

    maxconn 10

    timeout connect 100s
    timeout client  100s
    timeout server  100s
    timeout queue       100s

    # Stat page, http://example.com:8010/stats
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats refresh 10s
    stats show-node
    stats uri /stats
    stats realm Strictly\ Private
    stats auth username:password
```

I get these errors:

```
 * Starting haproxy haproxy                                                     
[ALERT] 218/022327 (1780) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:6] : unknown keyword 'tune.ssl.default-dh-param' in 'global' section
[ALERT] 218/022327 (1780) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:22] : 'redirect' expects 'code', 'prefix', 'location', 'set-cookie', 'clear-cookie', 'drop-query' or 'append-slash' (was 'scheme').
[ALERT] 218/022327 (1780) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:25] : 'bind' only supports the 'transparent', 'defer-accept', 'name', 'id', 'mss' and 'interface' options.
[ALERT] 218/022327 (1780) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 218/022327 (1780) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

It seems that it doesn't recognize OpenSSL functions.. Doesn anyone have an idea why???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the problem.. I have to modifiy the startup script `/etc/init.d/haproxy` to tell it where the newly compiled haproxy binary is.

I have to change this line `HAPROXY=/usr/sbin/haproxy` to this `HAPROXY=/usr/local/sbin/haproxy`.

Now it works.. =)

Comment: I had this problem today. For me it was unrelated to the init script, but because haproxy had not been compiled with openSSL support. yum install openssl-devel, then clean recompile of haproxy fixed it